# SQL Server Service Broker queue error: "The Service Broker protocol transport is not available"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, service-broker

Am trying to set up communication between two endpoints, sending **`XML`** data from one server to another, have created security certificates and mirroring endpoints as suggested, set up **`TLS`** settings on both machines, but have hit a roadblock.

The sending server is placing entries in sys.transmission_queue, but every single one is stuck with a transmission_status value of:

> The Service Broker protocol transport is not available.

Anyone know what the problem here is or how to remedy it?

Comment: Wherever you have got the suggestion to create mirroring endpoints, was not the best place to look. You need Service Broker endpoints, not the mirroring ones.

Comment: I agree with @roger. What is the T-SQL for creating your endpoint?